# Rigth way for this CTE in Postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, common-table-expression

My goal is to pickup the id in the Soggetto entry and fill it into tipo and tipo2.I can't figure out how to write in the right way this CTE in Postgres via pg in nodejs. I'm little bit confused.

```
var query = client.query('WITH retid AS (INSERT INTO "Soggetto" (nome, cognome, "regSociale", "partIVA") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING id ), INSERT INTO "Tipologia" (privato, azienda) VALUES ($5, $6) SELECT id FROM retid, INSERT INTO "Tipologia2" (cliente, fornitore) VALUES ($7, $8) SELECT id FROM retid ',
                      [sog.nome, sog.cognome, sog.ragioneSociale, sog.partitaIva, sog.cliente, sog.fornitore, sog.privato, sog.azienda], function(err, result){
                        if(err){
                          console.log(err);
                        }else{
                          res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
                          res.end('Insert ok');
                        }
                      });
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Does it work outside of Node.js? What is the result you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is not correct.  It is unclear exactly what you want, but each CTE needs its own name.  So, something like this:

```
WITH retid AS (
      INSERT INTO "Soggetto" (nome, cognome, "regSociale", "partIVA")
          VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
          RETURNING id
     ),
     t as (
      INSERT INTO "Tipologia" (privato, azienda)
          VALUES ($5, $6)
     ),
     t2 as (
      INSERT INTO "Tipologia2" (cliente, fornitore)
          VALUES ($7, $8)
     )
SELECT id
FROM retid;
```

Comment: Graet it'works no more errors....but i don't see Soggetto id in tipologia and tipologia2.soggetto_id is the column for store that value in tipo and tipo2.

Comment: The values being inserted are the values in the parameters, not the returned value.  This answers the question that you asked.  You should probably ask *another* question, providing sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.